# Completing an excercise regarding scopes and attributes in Ruby. Trying to debug code but it won't show me any error messages in the terminal

Tags: ruby

```
class LayingHen
  @@age = 0
  $basket = []
  $hatchedhours = 0
  # Ages the hen one month, and lays 4 eggs if the hen is older than 3 months
  def age!
    @@age+=1
    if @@age > 3 then for i in 1..4
      $basket << Egg.new
      end
    end
  end
  def age
    @@age
  end

  public
  # Returns +true+ if the hen has laid any eggs, +false+ otherwise
  def any_eggs?
    if $basket.count == 0 then false else true
    end
  end
   # Returns an Egg if there are any
  # Raises a NoEggsError otherwise
  def pick_an_egg!
    raise NoEggsError, "The hen has not layed any eggs" unless self.any_eggs?
    # egg-picking logic goes here
    $basket.sample
  end
  # Returns +true+ if the hen can't laid eggs anymore because of its age, +false+ otherwise.
  # The max age for a hen to lay eggs is 10 
  def old?
    if @@age > 10 then true else false
    end
  end

  def increase_hatched_hour(hours)
    $hatchedhours + hours = $hatchedhours
  end
 end

class Egg
  def initialize
  end
# Return +true+ if hatched hours is greater than 3, +false+ otherwise
  def rotten?
    if $hatchedhours > 3 then true else false
    end
  end
end


hen = LayingHen.new
rotten_eggs = 0
hen.age! until hen.any_eggs?
puts "Hen is #{hen.age} months old, its starting to laid eggs."
puts ""
until hen.old?
    #The time we take to pick up the eggs
   hours = rand(5)
   hen.increase_hatched_hour(hours)
  while hen.any_eggs?
    egg = hen.pick_an_egg!
    if egg.rotten?
      rotten_eggs += 1
    else
      $basket << egg
    end
  end
  puts "Month #{hen.age} Report"
  puts "We took #{hours} hour(s) to pick the eggs"
  puts "Eggs in the basket: #{$basket.size}"
  puts "Rotten eggs: #{rotten_eggs}"
  puts ""
  hen.age!
end
puts "The hen is old, she can't laid more eggs!"
puts "The hen laid #{$basket.size + rotten_eggs} eggs"
if rotten_eggs == 0
  puts "CONGRATULATIONS NO ROTTEN EGGS" 
else
  puts "We pick to late #{rotten_eggs} eggs so they become rotten"
end
```

I just can't seem to find where the error is, terminal does not give me any error messages or anything I'm getting really confused. I tried debugging but I'm just causing more errors and getting more confused, really have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have not stated what is occuring

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". You have to help us help you by reducing the code to the bare minimum that duplicates the problem, then creating a detailed question that tells us what's wrong. Don't make us copy, paste, and run the code, instead tell us what you're seeing returned for error text.

Comment: `$hatchedhours + hours = $hatchedhours`? That's an error. You're using globals when you should use class variables, though I'd probably use instance variables so you could have more than one hen. Your `if $hatchedhours > 3 then true else false end` type statements are wrong and can be simplified. Some of the method names are questionable, like `age!` which I'd call `add_year`. `old?` I'd call `max_age?` or `too_old?`